# Getting albums of multiple artist

Tags: android, api, deezer

I'm working in an Android app that will need to show all the albums of the favorite artists of the user sorted by released date.

Right now the only way that I see to do this is to get the list of artist by a request, and then launch another request by artist getting all the albums. Obviously I don't think this is efficient at all, and I was guessing if there is any way of getting the full list in a single request (or a couple of them).

At same time I will like to ask if there is any way of knowing witch album is a official release and witch one not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no shortcuts for that unfortunately. I think you're already making the right requests.